# Filter record based on its child element

Tags: xslt

I need to filter Record with `empinfo.class ='S'`  and exclude Record with any other `empinfo.class` (complete Record including its childs should be excluded).

The XSLT code I use returns me also the record that has one `empinfo.class='S'` but other `empinfo.class` too (Not Expected)

Input xml:

```
<Root>
<Record>
    <emp>
        <empid>1</empid>
        ...
        <empInfo>
            <class>S</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
        <empInfo>
            <class>G</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
        <empInfo>
            <class>G</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
    </emp>
</Record>
<Record>
    <emp>
        <empid>2</empid>
        ...
        <empInfo>
            <class>S</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
        <empInfo>
            <class>G</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
    </emp>
</Record>
<Record>
    <emp>
        <empid>3</empid>
        ...
        <empInfo>
            <class>S</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
    </emp>
</Record>
</Root>
```

XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Root">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Record[emp/empInfo/class='G' 
and emp/empInfo/class    ='S']"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output xml:

```
<Root>
<Record>
        <emp>
              <empid>3</empid>
        ...
        <empInfo>
                    <class>S</class>
            ...
        </empInfo>
        </emp>
  </Record>
</Root>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738) appropriately. This time I've done this for you - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this template

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record/emp">
            <xsl:if test="count(empInfo[class != 'S']) = 0">
                <Record>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </Record>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
<Root>
   <Record>
      <emp>
         <empid>3</empid>
         <empInfo>
            <class>S</class>
         </empInfo>
      </emp>
   </Record>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all `Record` elements which have no `emp/empInfo/class` descendants different to `S` you can use the predicate `Record[not(emp/empInfo/class != 'S')]`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="Root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="Record[not(emp/empInfo/class != 'S')]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTv